# Android swipelayout not working on all devices

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I implemented [this library](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout) in order to make gmail effect with swipe. I have tested and works fine, but it doesn't swipe at all on some devices. Any one met similar problem and solution for this issue ??

**PlayersAdapter.class**

```
public class PlayersAdapter extends RecyclerSwipeAdapter<PlayersAdapter.clientViewHolder> {

    protected SwipeItemRecyclerMangerImpl mItemManger = new SwipeItemRecyclerMangerImpl(this);
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<User> players;
    private PlayersFragment fragment;

    public PlayersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> players, PlayersFragment fragment) {
        this.context = context;
        this.players = players;
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public clientViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == Constants.ACTIVE_CONSUMER) {
            return new clientViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.active_client_item, parent, false), Constants.ACTIVE_CONSUMER);
        } else {
            return new clientViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.invited_client_item, parent, false), Constants.INVITED_CONSUMER);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (players.get(position).getStatus().equals(Constants.STATUS_INVITED)) {
            return Constants.INVITED_CONSUMER;
        }
        return Constants.ACTIVE_CONSUMER;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final clientViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        final User player = players.get(position);
        int screenWidth = UIUtils.getScreenWidth((Activity) context);
        int screen = screenWidth - screenWidth / 4;

        if (player.getStatus().equals(Constants.STATUS_INVITED)) {
            viewHolder.rlRemove.getLayoutParams().width = screen / 3;
            viewHolder.rlPlayerEdit.getLayoutParams().width = screen / 3;
            viewHolder.rlPlayerEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    viewHolder.swipeLayout.close();
                    editClient(player.getId());
                }
            });

            viewHolder.rlSendAnotherInvitation.getLayoutParams().width = screen / 3;
            viewHolder.rlSendAnotherInvitation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                        viewHolder.swipeLayout.close();

                    } else {

                        viewHolder.swipeLayout.close();
                    }
                }
            });

            viewHolder.rlPlayerOptions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (viewHolder.swipeLayout.getOpenStatus() == SwipeLayout.Status.Open) {
                        viewHolder.swipeLayout.close();
                    } else {
                        viewHolder.swipeLayout.open();
                        AnimationUtils.setFadeInAnimation(viewHolder.rlRemove, AnimationUtils.DELAY_DURATION);
                        AnimationUtils.setFadeInAnimation(viewHolder.rlPlayerEdit, AnimationUtils.DELAY_DURATION * 2);
                        AnimationUtils.setFadeInAnimation(viewHolder.rlSendAnotherInvitation, AnimationUtils.DELAY_DURATION * 3);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            viewHolder.rlRemove.getLayoutParams().width = screen;
            if (player.getImage() == null) {
                viewHolder.ivPlayerAvatar.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.user_ic));
            } else {
                final ProgressBar progressView = viewHolder.progressBar;
                progressView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressView.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.dark_blue), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(player.getImage().getSize128())
                        .fit()
                        .transform(new RoundedTransformation(15, 0))
                        .error(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.user_ic))
                        .into(viewHolder.ivPlayerAvatar, new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                progressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError() {
                                progressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
            }

            viewHolder.rlPlayerOptions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (viewHolder.swipeLayout.getOpenStatus() == SwipeLayout.Status.Open) {
                        viewHolder.swipeLayout.close();
                    } else {
                        viewHolder.swipeLayout.open();
                        AnimationUtils.setFadeInAnimation(viewHolder.rlRemove, AnimationUtils.DELAY_DURATION);

                    }
                }
            });

            viewHolder.clientRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
        }

        viewHolder.rlRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                viewHolder.swipeLayout.close();
            }
        });

        viewHolder.tvPlayerFullName.setText(players.get(position).getFullName());
        viewHolder.swipeLayout.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.PullOut);
        viewHolder.swipeLayout.addDrag(SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Right, viewHolder.swipeLayout.findViewById(R.id.options));
        viewHolder.swipeLayout.addSwipeListener(new SwipeLayout.SwipeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClose(SwipeLayout layout) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onUpdate(SwipeLayout layout, int leftOffset, int topOffset) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartClose(SwipeLayout layout) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onHandRelease(SwipeLayout layout, float xvel, float yvel) {

            }
        });

        mItemManger.bindView(viewHolder.itemView, position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return players.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getSwipeLayoutResourceId(int position) {
        return R.id.swipe;
    }

    public class clientViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        /**
         * Common UI Elements
         */
        private SwipeLayout swipeLayout;
        private TextView tvPlayerFullName;
        private RelativeLayout rlRemove;
        private RelativeLayout rlPlayerOptions;
        private ProgressBar progressBar;
        private ImageView ivPlayerAvatar;
        private RelativeLayout clientRow;

        /**
         * Invited Consumer UI Elements
         */
        private RelativeLayout rlPlayerEdit;
        private RelativeLayout rlSendAnotherInvitation;

        public clientViewHolder(View itemView, int status) {
            super(itemView);
            tvPlayerFullName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvClientFullName);
            swipeLayout = (SwipeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
            rlPlayerOptions = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivClientOptions);
            rlRemove = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rlRemove);
            clientRow = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.clientRow);
            ivPlayerAvatar = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.civClientAvatar);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

            if (status == Constants.INVITED_CONSUMER) {
                rlPlayerEdit = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rlEdit);
                rlSendAnotherInvitation = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rlSendAnotherInvitation);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**PlayersActivity.class**

```
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
                recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST, R.drawable.divider));
                mAdapter = new PlayersAdapter(context, players, PlayersFragment.this);
                (mAdapter).setMode(Attributes.Mode.Multiple);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```